# What's the best way to add a chat control with Python wxWidgets? (wxpython)

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm programming a chatbot that has an interface similar to MSN's one.

I need a control with white background that needs to be scrollable so it only shows most recent messages. I'm using a StaticText control but probably there's something better.

I understand that probably I could just create a label every time there's a new text and put that into a scrollable panel but I want to know if there's a better alternative.

Comment: why not richtext control?

Comment: @hhaamm, you can try to use a wxTextCtrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A readonly [wxTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html) (with [attributes](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html#a0d972d3007e23ed9270d16b6bb326e80) allowing you to use colours/bold/italic, but not much more), [wxRichTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_rich_text_ctrl.html) (with many more features, but quite a bit slower) or even [wxHtmlWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_html_window.html) would all be much better alternatives than using multiple `wxStaticText` controls.

Comment: Thanks, wxTextCtrl with multiple lines worked very well.